How to run Windows File Explorer as a stand-alone application, and not part of explorer.exe
I have an Elgato Streamdeck, and have put a similar question to their support team but I'm pretty sure they won't be able to help in this situation.  The Streamdeck is a hotkey hardware device that stores multiple profiles, and each one contains a different set of hotkeys, and depending on which application you're using it will update the hotkeys to match the set profile for that application.
I've created a hotkey profile for File Explorer and I've linked it to C:\Windows\explorer.exe (this is how I'd link a profile to any other application).  However, the trouble I'm having is that when I try and lick a hotkey profile to open with the File Explorer, it seems to default to it all the time.  I have a "default" profile set up, so that if one of my specific applications isn't open, it should show the default profile.
However the new File Explorer profile is overriding the default now.  I'm presuming this behaviour is because explorer.exe runs the whole GUI, as well as the File Explorer windows, and when on any part of the GUI, the streamdecks that explorer.exe is active.
So my question is, is there anyway to run File Explorer as a stand-alone application?  So that in task manager it would show as a completely separate entry and I could link to it separately?

No; There isn’t; You can only have one SHELL handler, and File Explorer, would have to be ran in order to have any resemblance of a desktop. Why did you select File Explorer?

I selected File Explorer because I want one of my profiles to show specifically for folder operations.  I would like to set up hotkey shortcuts specific to file explorer like creating folder structures, running folder / file scripts, archiving selected files and suchlike.

Windows Explorer is built into the OS; it manages the desktop. There are alternative third-party tools: https://alternativeto.net/software/windows-explorer/
